# error: Error parsing XML:unbound prefix

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am new to Android app development and i'm trying to debug my code and i get an error for line 7. The error type is APPT if that matters. As far as I can tell I do not see anything wrong with my code. If any has any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"> 

<TextView
    abdroid:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="OK"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ok"
    android:text="Cancel"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

looks like the problem. Try moving the `>` at the end to the end of `android:orientation="vertical"`.

EDIT:

You also have a typo. `abdroid:id="@+id/label"` should be `android:id="@+id/label"`

And make sure you end your file with `</RelativeLayout>` to close the relative layout element.

Comment: Well I had the closing tag must have missed it on the copy but the typo on android was the problem. Why didn't say the problem was on line 8?

Comment: I believe that is because the element containing it starts on line 7. Also, at least for me, when I hover over the error it says which prefix is unbound, so you can narrow it down within the element in that way.